The question of a curve is uniquely determined by an number of points
It is known that a line is uniquely determined by two of its points The circle is uniquely determined by three points, while the conical cut is determined by five points, and the cubic curve is determined by ten points, but I am looking for a A specific method to uniquely define curves through n points, knowing that the curve should not be a function, it should be free to move in the plane in terms of volume and rotation
Going tNote, even if you cannot answer the general situation it would be a good idea to provide answers about special cases, for example what is the curve that is uniquely determined by four points? Note that it is not a parabola because there is a pair of parabolas in the general case to pass from four points in the plane
Other curves I'm particularly interested in are those that need 6 or 7 points to uniquely define them, but I would certainly be happy to discuss the general case.
Note: My main concern is about a geometric definition of these curves, but algebraic definitions are okay if the general case cannot be addressed by geometry.

You say "what is the curve that is uniquely determined by four points? Note that it is not a parabola because there is a pair of parabolas in the general case" but you could then say that the parabola-pair is a curve determined by four points if you are willing to be flexible about the meaning of curve.

You're right @Henry, a pair of parabolas can be considered a unique curve that is determined by four points, but how can we define this curve in the general case, I mean we should not start with the definition from here, nor from the definition of a parabola because nothing special in the relative case where the two parabolas intersect by four points, on the whole a good suggestion but I still have some reservations about it

Bezier curves are uniquely defined by a set of $n$ points https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Explicit_definition

Bezier curves are not a solution to my problem, note that I treat all points the same way, I do not distinguish a starting point and an endpoint @whpowell96

About polynomial curves $P(x,y)=0$, see here.

and also here.
